# Cannot compile pallet_assets

Tags: assets

I receive:

```
   Compiling pallet-assets v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.30#a3ed0119)
error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope
   --> /Users/chp/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/a3ed011/frame/assets/src/functions.rs:673:46
    |
673 |         let mut dead_accounts: Vec<T::AccountId> = vec![];
    |                                                    ^^^
    |
    = note: consider importing one of these items:
            codec::alloc::vec
            scale_info::prelude::vec
            sp_std::vec
```

when I add pallet-assets.

Is this an error in my code? It feels like it is in the pallet.

Edit:

I run `cargo test` and this is in Cargo.toml

```
pallet-assets = { 
    version = "4.0.0-dev",
    default-features = false,
    git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git",
    branch = "polkadot-v0.9.30" 
}
```

Comment: Please share your `Cargo.toml` and the command that you used to compile. Most likely there is something wrong with the Rust features in your Cargo file.

Comment: I use `cargo test` and `pallet-assets = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.30" }
`

Comment: https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#klta1t9riihefykzccl6v4 -> Full Cargo.toml

Comment: Got it. Need to balances and assets add it to `std`!

Comment: Okay answering so we can mark it as solved.

Comment: There are so many similar questions like this. Please close this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ensure that your `Cargo.toml` adds the pallet with the correct features:

```
# Default features are disabled.
pallet-assets = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", default-features = false, branch = "polkadot-v0.9.31" }

[features]
default = [ "std" ]
std = [ "pallet-assets/std" ]
runtime-benchmarks = [ "pallet-assets" ]
```